# GemFury is throwing 502s for our private repository, is there anything we can do to mitigate this?

Tags: gem-fury

We're seeing 502s when pulling packages from our private repository, Gemfury hasn't yet addressed the issue in their status dashboard. Is anyone else seeing this issue as well?

https://status.fury.co/
https://github.com/gemfury/gemfury/issues/78

Comment: I'm having the same here. Hope they fix it soon.